# What does the "scale" setting when plotting a NDVI or EVI time series?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, scale, chart, plotting

I adapted the script from the guide for [ui.Chart.image.series](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection#uichartimageseries) to my region of interest and time period:

```
// Import the example feature collection and subset the forest feature.
var bm = ee.FeatureCollection("users/fulano_letal/ROI_BM_Mayor100ha_Veg1aria");

// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset a time period of images.
var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31'))
                     .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: vegIndices,
          region: bm,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 50000,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['EVI', 'NDVI'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average Vegetation Index Value by Date for BM',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Vegetation index (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chart);
```

And my question is about the "scale" setting in the ui.Chart.image part, I don't understand what it does and therefore I don't know which value I should use.

I ran a series of comparisons varying the scale with different values (5, 25, 250, 500, 5000, 50000) but still don't understand.

So, can you advise me the "scale" value I should use?

[image: Comparison of different scales]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale setting in any function of EarthEngine sets the size of the pixel to use.

In your example, you chart the `mean` of the `NDVI` value of your geometry.  If you set the scale to 50000 (in meters) your pixel size is 50km X 50km.  So the calculation of your chart would be very quick.

Depending on your geometry, if you set a scale to 5 (in meters) it would mean that your chart will be using 100000000 more pixels to do the calculation (which could take some time and possibly reach a limit of the your calculation, and give you an error.

Looking back at your chart, if your geometry is a farm field of 20 hectares (2km X 2km) your earlier pixel of 50km X 50 km would include a lot of extra info that isn't part of your field.

Same example, with a pixel of 5m X 5m, you would only include info that you need.  (any pixels outside your geometry would be ignored).

The `MOD13Q1` you are using has a pixel size of 250m.  The "best" you can do is 250m.  Any scale smaller than that, would just add noise, and cost time.  So I would suggest you use a pixel size of 250 (in meters).

I hope this clarification is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now it is clear to me that this setting should be accord with the resolution of the product that I want to measure.

Comment: Just to clarify, the [MOD13Q1](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD13Q1) has a pixel size of 250m so, following your advice, I will use that number in Scale. Thank's again!

Comment: I misread the documentation...  I have edited my answer to reflect the correct pixel size.  Thanks.